# Group list values by KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, algorithm, list

Say i have a list

```
[1,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,3,3,1,3,3,2,3]
```

[image]

Any ideas how to group them (`List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>`) so that the key is the next smallest digit, and Value is next biggest digit, and if it repeats itself, group it with the same smallest key, if that makes sense...

This is the output that I am looking for:

```
[Key, Value]
[0,1]
[0,2]
[3,4]
[3,5]
[3,6]
[7,8]
[7,9]
[10,11]
[10,12]
[13,14]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You can use `SortedList<int,List<int>>`. When you need to output - simply iterate through all the keys (don't forget to use the `List.Sort` method before start iterating. if you want I can easily share a snippet

Comment: foreach loop, then if statements to check for + 1 or -1 offset based on current index. that works fine if there are no identical numbers more then 2 offsets left or right. I tried to run a while loop for each index to find min max value but have trouble getting my head around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the image and the example input:

```
       var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3}; //example input

        var results = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
        int key = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if(i==0 || list[i] < list[i - 1])                
                key = i++; //assign key and proceed to next index (NB no index out of range checking)                
            results.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(key, i));
        }
```

This uses a direct comparison with the previous element and uses the indices as key and values as in the example output. If the key value is always smaller than the previous element as in your description, you could replace the if with: `if(i==0 || list[i] < list[i - 1])`

*edit*, made the Tuple a KeyValuePair

Comment: You are correct, the key value is always smaller then the previous element. Thanks for this. This works :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    private static void foo()
    {
        SortedList<int, List<int>> collection = new SortedList<int, List<int>>();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        // Filling the collection with random keys/values:
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int key = rnd.Next(0, 10);
            if (!collection.ContainsKey(key))
                collection.Add(key, new List<int>());
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                int value = rnd.Next(0, 1000);
                collection[key].Add(value);
            }
        }

        // Displaying all pairs:
        foreach (var key in collection.Keys)
        {
            collection[key].Sort();
            for (int j = 0; j < collection[key].Count; j++)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0},{1}]", key, collection[key][j]));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> input = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3 };
            int previous = 0;
            int keyIndex = 0;
            Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    keyIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (input[i] < previous)
                    {
                        keyIndex = i;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (dict.ContainsKey(keyIndex))
                        {
                            dict[keyIndex].Add(i);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dict.Add(keyIndex, new List<int>(){ i});
                        }
                    }
                }
                previous = input[i];
            }

            foreach (int dictKey in dict.Keys)
            {
                var l = dict[dictKey];

                Console.WriteLine("Key:{0}, values={1}", dictKey, string.Join(",", dict[dictKey].Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will solve your issue

```
public void GetPairs()
{
     List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1,3,3,2,3,3,1,3,4,1 };

     List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> kvapar = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
     int prev = 0, firstIndex = 0, lastIndex = 0;
     foreach (int i in list)
     {
          if (i < prev)
          {
              kvapar.AddRange(GetRange(list.GetRange(firstIndex, lastIndex)));
              firstIndex += lastIndex; lastIndex = 0;
          }
          prev = i; lastIndex++;
     }
} 
public List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> GetRange(List<int> list)
{
       List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> result = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
       foreach(int i in list)
       {
           if (list.IndexOf(i) == 0) continue;
           result.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(list[0], i));
       }
           return result;
}
```